# Final Render is glitchy and not what I see in Camera Viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I'm a noob here so please be easy on me. I've searched around the forums with no answers to my problem that I could find. I've spent quite a long time (because I'm a noob) getting this to look the way I want it, yet when I render the image I am receiving a very strange result. The City was a Blender file downloaded from CGTrader. I did detach the Environment HDRI node and used a plane for lighting instead. The character is from Mixamo, but it appears as if the problem lies with the city modeling. Inside blender this looks fine when viewing with cycles as you can see in my screenshot. Blender is still so complex to me so any help or ideas are appreciated [image: What the final render looks like]

[image: What I see in my Viewport and want the final render to look like]

Comment: Not sure what's going on, however a clue is that the color pink like that, in blender, means "missing texture". Blender can't find your images - Usually a path error

Comment: I suspect you have objects in the city file that are enabled for render but not for viewport display.  You can check this in the outliner.  If that's not the case, please add your blend file to your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable the FILTERS in the outliner (Yellow) and activate the Monitor and the camera.
If an object has a MONITOR off and the CAMERA ON, it means you will not see it on your viewport, but it will be visible FOR RENDER.
So you need to completely explore your scene using these filters to see which one is the object that is appearing at render time.
Also: Don't give up, you're doing pretty well for a N00b (Mixamo+city assets?!) :)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have things hidden in Viewport but not in Render, make sure to check those out.